# HTML Form misplaced

Tags: html, forms, view

I have a simple HTML form with some validations but the text labels get misplaced when the form appears.

This is the form before (**PLEASE NOTE:** The red square around it is not part of the form, I just placed it with Paint to help you see the problem quick):

[image]

And after:

[image]

Any hint to keep the label aligned with the text field please?
**UPDATE:**

This is the code:

```
<form name="senstageaddform">

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="ed_senStartDate" class="text-label">
            {{i18n "EDUCATION_SEN_START_DATE"}} <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="date standard-text-field" maxlength="16" id="ed_senStartDate" name="startDate"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="ed_senEndDate" class="text-label">{{i18n "EDUCATION_SEN_END_DATE"}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="date standard-text-field" maxlength="16" id="ed_senEndDate" name="endDate"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.form-element {
    display: inline-block; margin: 5px; width: 98%; clear: both; vertical-align:top

.text-label {
    width: 20%; text-align: right; display: inline-block; padding: 3px 5px 0px 1px; 
}

.standard-text-field {
    width: 10em;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code so we can see what is happening? I would guess it has something to do with the extra border in red. This needs to be taken into account for the widths of the containers

Comment: I would try to put the label and the input in the same container and have them next to each other.

Comment: @pateman I don't think that that border has something to do with this. It's probably added to the screenshot. OP, please also add your css :)

Comment: @Robin both them are in the same container. I thought that will solve the issue as well, but it is not unfortunately.

Comment: Code shared @pateman , please note that the extra border is not part of the form, I just added it with MS Paint

Comment: @AlexG ah yes I see. I would still think it has to do with widths of the containers, but with out the code structure you can't tell.

Comment: CSS added @AlexG thank you very much to all

Comment: I am not 100% with the use of 'em' but when you add the error message the 'form-element' expands and so there is a measurement difference between using the 'em' and the '%' . The 'standard-text-field' is then bigger than can fit in the 'form-element'. I would keep it consistent and use a '%' width for both.

Comment: @pateman nice one, but it doesn't work as well